# How to select the recent date item

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I hava a table USER:

```
select t.* from user t;
uid  uname
1    tom
2    jim
3    bob
4    lily
```

and table TOYS

```
select t.* from toys t;
tid  uid  tdate
1    1    7/12/15
2    1    6/12/15
3    2    9/12/15
4    2    10/12/15
5    3    12/12/15
```

now I want

```
uid  tid   uname  tdate
1    2     tom    6/12/15
2    3     jim    9/12/15
3    5     bob    12/12/15
4          lily
```

what should I do?  (I use oracle database);

Comment: do you want the toys with users sorted by date or the users with the most recent toy only?

Comment: with a minimal date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a sequence for each user and pull back only the min date for each toy:

```
SELECT user.uid, toys.tid, user.name, toys.tdate 
  FROM    
      (SELECT tid, uid, tdate, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY tdate asc)
      AS SEQ
      FROM toys
     )table1
LEFT JOIN user on toys.uid = user.uid
WHERE SEQ = 1
```

Comment: you think is right, but you are write incorrect。

Answer (score 0):

most recent tdate per toy and user:

```
SELECT a.uid, b.tid, a.uname, MAX(b.tdate) AS tdate
FROM user a LEFT JOIN toys b ON a.uid = b.uid 
GROUP BY a.uid, b.tid, a.uname
```

or most recent toy per user (if any):

```
SELECT a.uid, b.tid, a.uname, MAX(b.tdate) 
FROM user a LEFT JOIN toys b ON a.uid = b.uid 
GROUP BY a.uid, a.uname
```

Comment: this sql can't execute